# What is the word for the state of being offended?

Tags: nouns

For instance, if I am mad, I can manage my madness, grumpy people exist in a state of grumpiness.  What is the noun associated with being offended?  Offendedness doesn't seem right

Comment: It sounds like you're offended that there is no such term.

Comment: Perhaps, _sensitive_ to comments?

Comment: *Offendedness* is good enough for Salman Rushdie http://www.salon.com/2013/08/15/salman_rushdie_we_live_in_a_culture_of_offendedness/

Comment: I'm fond of *dudgeon*.

Comment: Isn't it just *offence*? Otherwise, I like "umbrage".

Comment: I’m a bit out of popular culture, so I can’t be sure, but isn’t it the “woke” thing I keep hearing? (Or should it be “woken”?)

Answer (score 1):

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/offendedness) lists "offendedness" as an acceptable noun:

> **Related forms**
>
> - offendable, *adjective*
> - offendedly, *adverb*
> - **offendedness**, *noun*
> - offender, *noun*
> - half-offended, *adjective*

But I do agree with you that it sounds a bit stilted. Regardless, it is still correct.

---

Though there is no synonymous noun (none that I can find, at least), there are alternatives that you can use.

Using a gerund, you can convert a verb into a noun. This means that "to take offense" and "to be offended" are valid when you use them as a gerund:

> - I tried to avoid **taking offense**.
> - I know I am sensitive to **being offended**.

Answer (score 0):

Despite being constantly cautioned by Windows, I use offendedness, as there doesn't seem to be any exact synonym for the state. e.g.: "We live in a climate of perpetual offendedness, the society of the inherently aggrieved."

Comment: This is essentially the same as the previous answer.