# What noun do we have that means 'offendableness' or 'offendability' (tendency) or that means 'offendedness' (state)?

Tags: expressions, derivational-morphology

I found only one relevant response at [What is the word for the state of being offended?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408130/what-is-the-word-for-the-state-of-being-offended)

Any others?

> "Offendedness is good enough for Salman Rushdie
>   ([www.salon.com](https://www.salon.com/2013/08/15/salman_rushdie_we_live_in_a_culture_of_offendedness/))
>   – Spagirl Aug 31 '17 at 13:16"

Answer (score 2):

Being **[thin skinned](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thin+skinned)** is to be easily offended. This usage is idiomatic.

> Emotionally susceptible to or unable to ignore the verbal attacks or
>   criticisms of others.

As in:

> You can't be thin-skinned if you want to be in the entertainment
>   industry.

Answer (score 1):

Irascible: having or showing a tendency to be easily angered.

Irascibility: The more you 'ave, the less you 'are

Comment: Being angered isn't the same as being offended. You can be angered as a result of offense, but you can also be upset, repelled, sad, numb, and more.

Answer (score 1):

This state could be called [**touchy**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/touchy):

> Tending to take offense with slight cause; oversensitive.